# What does Python consider as True or False for each primitive Type?

Tags: python, evaluation, nonetype, expression-evaluation

```
def toBeOrNotToBe(x, y):
    return x or y

print(toBeOrNotToBe(0,1))
print(toBeOrNotToBe([],[1,2,3]))
print(toBeOrNotToBe('','something'))
print(toBeOrNotToBe(None, lambda _: None))
```

```
1
[1, 2, 3]
something
<function <lambda> at 0x0000015A20538708>
```

Where can I find the complete list for what Python is considering as True or False for every Type ?
How can I write my own methods for my Classes ?

Comment: def toBeOrNotToBe(x, y):
    return bool(x) or bool(y) is True

Answer (score 0):

> ## Truth Value Testing
>
> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use
>   in an `if` or `while` condition or as operand of the Boolean operations
>   below.
>
> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines
>   either a `__bool__()` method that returns False or a `__len__()` method
>   that returns zero, when called with the object. Here are most of the
>   built-in objects considered false:
>
> - constants defined to be false: None and False.
> - zero of any numeric type: 0, 0.0, 0j, Decimal(0), Fraction(0, 1)
> - empty sequences and collections: '', (), [], {}, set(), range(0)
>
> Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always
>   return `0` or `False` for false and `1` or `True` for true, unless otherwise
>   stated. (Important exception: the Boolean operations `or` and `and` always
>   return one of their operands.)

[More details can be found here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Comment: Please do not post images of text. People with processing issues and people with screen readers cannot (easily) read those. I will edit your answer to correct that, just leaving comment for future consideration. :)